# asp net c# DateTime convert o javascript date

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, date, datetime

Hi I am having trouble converting a asp net DateTime to a javascript Date().

Usually when we get dates from asp net it is of the format
"/Date(1427101769000)/"
This Date in asp net is 
"{3/23/2015 9:09:29 AM}"

So in this case I would parse the string for the millis and then use the javascript Date constructor with the millis like:

```
var curDate = new Date(1427101769000);
```

However this value becomes
Mon Mar 23 2015 02:09:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time).
When it was supposed to be {3/23/2015 9:09:29 AM} from the server.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: are you familiar with the String.Format() function as well as the Date.ToString() function along with possibly using the string.Format function..there are tons of examples online in regards to how to format a date.. have you tried a google search..?

Comment: choose the datetime format to display: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

"{3/23/2015 9:09:29 AM}"

Do you notice what's missing from this expression?  The second date should make it clear:

"Mon Mar 23 2015 02:09:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"

Specifically, the first date is missing a timezone.  If it's missing a timezone, it's assumed to be in UTC (-0000).

So, the two are displaying the same time, just the first in UTC (-0000) and the second in PDT (-0700).  Which is why the PDT time is displaying the hours as 7 hours earlier.

This is because time in millis is based on UNIX time, which is itself based on the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970, 12:00am UTC.  Being milliseconds instead of seconds, there are an extra 3 digits at the end.

Comment: The *reason* its missing a timezone is murkier, though.  Presumably, JavaScript makes a new Data object have the timezone of the computer it is on.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Date constructor takes in a Unix timestamp in milliseconds as a parameter, and the browser/client will convert it to its local timezone when printing it out as a string.